# Change text color dynamically in Wordpress

Tags: css, navigation

I would like to have a transparent nav bar. On the landing page, there will be a slider with images of varying colors, so I would like to change the text color of menu items to contrast against each respective image.

A solution I found here seemed ideal: https://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/bWWwGa

However, when I implement here in an HTML builder: https://cutt.ly/KwyC2av, it outputs a totally different effect. Same code, same browser, so I'm assuming it's Wordpress?

`mix-blend-mode: difference` also seems to have no effect when I've applied it to other selectors from the stylesheet. Is there a reason WP won't output the same as the codepen?

I would love a pure CSS solution if possible. JS as a last resort is doable, but not preferable. I have found SASS solutions, but have no idea what to do with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you inspect the text, you'll see that your theme's CSS is overriding your custom CSS.

You have `h2 { color: white; }`

but your theme has `.widget h2 { color: inherit; }`

so "inherit" wins out. If you change your own CSS to

`.widget h2 { color: white; }`

it will override the theme. Incidentally, the markup here is quite overly complex; you might want to look into a simpler theme without quite so many nested divs.

Comment: Thanks so much! I just needed to confirm that snippet would work. Now I need to confirm why it won't apply to the nav li. (I successfully changed the color in the inspector, so I know I'm in the correct selector).

Comment: You might try enqueueing your CSS rather than just adding it to the page in the HTML below. You can add the theme CSS as a dependency to ensure your file loads after the theme's and should in theory override it - unless the theme has a more specific rule.